# Using Realize Instances node in Blender distorts/deforms/messes up/ breaks original shape (Curve based mesh)

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to generate pipes from a shapefile I loaded in Blender via the Blender GIS plugin.

So far I have exactly the result I want from using geometry nodes, and now I want to convert it to a mesh.

Using Realize Instances node in Blender distorts/deforms/messes up/ breaks original shape (Curve based mesh).

Is there any way to "lock" the model before the realize instances is applied so this distortion doesn't occur?

Edit: redoing the geometry nodes in another file, allowed blender to render everything correctly, could be a problem related to memory. After applying the "make instances real" geometry node, in the properties of the lines I applied the geometry nodes and the resulting mesh was finally exportable to other 3D formats like FBX in the picture. (Loaded in Unity).

[image]

Comment: What are you wanting  the _Realize Instances_ node to do, here? There are no obvious instances to be realized?

Comment: I'm trying to convert my resulting 3D from a line (First picture) into a mesh but if I try Object->Apply->Make instances real   everything disappears.  I read in another stackexchange that I could use the "Realize instances" node before applying the "Make instances real" command.  It does indeed generate a mesh but when I apply the realize instances node my original model distorts resulting on the second image.

Comment: After _Curve to Mesh_, you have a mesh. Is applying the modifier not working for you? Maybe share on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I somehow managed to make it work!  I was cleaning a new file to upload it on blend-exchange and when I tried without the other layers and files loaded (LOTS of data) it managed to make instances real and I was able to finally export my mesh as a FBX file.

I think it may be something related to Blender and the available memory it has to work with? It is definitely a weird behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redoing the geometry nodes in another file, allowed blender to render everything correctly, could be a problem related to memory. After applying the "make instances real" geometry node, in the properties of the lines I applied the geometry nodes and the resulting mesh was finally exportable to other 3D formats like FBX in the picture. (Loaded in Unity).

Comment: Hi @Rocho ! Glad you found a way. You can accept your own answer ( by clicking on the tick, ) and that will mark your problem as solved.